# Convert particle to Mesh in Blender 2.90?

Tags: mesh

Hi have two particle systems in my project and I want to convert them to a mesh. When I press "convert", a mesh is created in the hierarchy, but actually it contains nothing.

[image]

[image]

I am either doing something wrong or something is not working.

Comment: When you convert the particles, are you on a frame other than 0?

Comment: it seams to work, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/